# VIM: Open multiple file in specfic order

Tags: vim

So I want to start off with this: I understand that I can open multiple files with `vim *`,`vim */file.txt`,`vim directory/*`, etc.

What I am looking for is this use-case:

I have a directory of two folders, each with three files. I wish to open two of the four files in a specific order in all ten of the folders. Visualized:

```
->a
  |->a
  |->b
  |->c
->b
  |->a
  |->b
  |->c
```

I wish to open in this order:

```
a/c
a/a
b/c
b/a
```

This is the minimum use case, in practice, I'm applying this over a hundred files.

Comment: For your minimum case, brace expansion should suffice (`vim {a,b}/{c,a}`)

Comment: Perhaps expand on your use case. You want to open hundred files at the same time for interactive editing?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks - so in this particular use case, it looks like my answer would be `vim */{c,a}`

Comment: @steeldriver - So yours works for the minimum case. Just tried wildcard. Its opening `a/a,b/a,c/a,...,a/c,b/c,c/c...`

Comment: @vanadium let directory equal `X` and file equal `Y`. Assume `X` is infinite, `Y` is the set `{a,b,c}`

Comment: steeldriver pointed you in the right direction/ `*/{c,a}' will open files c and a in any of the directories. Imagining X to be "infinite" does not particularly clarify the use case of opening hundreds of files for interactive editing to me, though.

Comment: @vanadium I'm looking for shorthand for this: `vim {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}/{c,a}`. `*/{c,a}` will not work because it opens every `c` before every `a`. `c` and `a` must alternate.

Comment: This is a case where `sed` won't work because the files are not yet uniform in internals. Some manual coaxing is needed to get them there :)

Comment: A `for ... do` loop may work perhaps, although then you should be able to reconnect to the running vim instance. Still, I find it hard to imagine why you would simultaneously open 100 files for interactive editing.

Comment: Shorthand for `{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}/{c,a}` would be `{a..z}/{c,a}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
TMP=$(mktemp); ARG= ; for d in * ;  do ARG=\"$d/\"{c,a}\ $ARG ;  done ;  echo "vim $ARG" > $TMP ;  . $TMP ;  rm $TMP
```

A temporary file is created to hold the final command. A variable `ARG` is initialized. A `for ... do` loop creates a list of the files in the desired order into the variable. The command line is written to the temporary file and sourced from there. Once you close the editor, the temporary file will be removed.

The length of arguments is limited, so that is one factor that will impose a limit on the number of files you simultaneously can open this way.

Comment: YES. That accomplishes exactly what I was looking for.